# Error incompatible pointer type?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char getInput(char *x[50]);

main (){

char string[50];
getInput(&string);
}

char getInput(char *x[50]){
printf("What is the string?");
gets(*x);   
}
```

I keep getting these errors...

exer7.c:20:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘getInput’ from incompatible pointer type   [enabled by default]
  getInput(&string);
  ^
**exer7.c:5:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[50]’
 char getInput(char *x[50]);**

I've been changing the pointers and ampersands but I really don't know the proper pointer type, pls help :(

BTW, that's just a code snippet, I have many other user-declared functions I don't need to post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void getInput(char (*x)[50]);

int main (){
    char string[50];
    getInput(&string);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`char *x[50]` declares `x` as `array of pointers.`&string` is of type *pointer to an array*. Both types are incompatible.

Change your function declaration to

```
char getInput(char x[50]);
```

and call it as

```
 getInput(string);
```

Comment: ahh so you don't have to use pointers to automatically update the value like with ints and floats... thanks :)

Comment: In fact, array names are converted to pointer to its first element when passed to a function in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

`getInput(&string);` You shouldn't pass `&` of `string`. Just base address `string` of the char array need to be passed as the argument.

`char getInput(char *x[50]);` This formal argument isn't correct too. This should be a pointer to char or array of char of 50 bytes.